# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest [Error happened while processing request]

Tags: powershell, httpwebrequest, invoke-webrequest

I am working on a project to automate creating AD users, creating folders in the different departments/sections for the users, also send password automatically when AD user is created to their cellphones & startup package in the user company mail.

I am having a problem doing this in PowerShell, this works great in Python (my main language). I get this odd error when trying to process my request in powershell.

Code:

```
$url = "hiding_this_for_obvious_reasons" # Request URL

$nummer = Read-Host("Skriv inn mobil nummer: ")
$tekst = Read-Host("Skriv inn melding: ")

#Request Payload information
$JSON = @'
{
            "content": "$tekst",
            "senderNumber": "SSB",
            "targetNumbersAsDelimitedString": "47$nummer",
            "sendDate": null,
            "status": {"id": "5"},
            "numberOfTargetNumbers": null,
            "numberOfInvalidNumbers": ""
}
'@

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType "application/json"
```

The error message as follows:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Error happened while processing request 
At H:\Scripts\Powershell Scripts\ClearAD\SendSMSPowershell.ps1:19 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType "ap ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use variables but inside single quotes. It needs to be double quotes for the variables to be expanded.

Try this:

```
$JSON = @"
{
            "content": "$tekst",
            "senderNumber": "SSB",
            "targetNumbersAsDelimitedString": "47$nummer",
            "sendDate": null,
            "status": {"id": "5"},
            "numberOfTargetNumbers": null,
            "numberOfInvalidNumbers": ""
}
"@
```

Comment: Ah i see, i'm a python programmer so powershell isnt really my area. Anyways i do still get the same error after the change. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately the error is otherwise too vague. My guess would be that you're not sending the JSON that it expects.

Comment: Actually the code you sent worked, it just sent an error anyways, even though i received the SMS. Thanks man! :D

Answer (score 0):

This works for me where I have been trying to do this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $header -Method POST -ContentType "text/plain" -Body $body
```

and the endpoint keeps coming back with

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"code":"Invalid_Request","message":"An error occurred reading the request
> body.","correlationId":"xxxxxx"}

where the content of the $body variable was

```
$body = @{
      'userId' = $userId
      'username'  = $userename
}
```

and it worked when I replaced the above with

```
$body = @"
        {
            "userID": "$userId",
            "username": "$username"
        }
"@
```

I'd be interested in knowing why?